# Binary Tree implementation using Comparable in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, comparable

I am trying to implement a Binary Tree  class.Here's the insert method.When I compile it I get an error as **"uses unchecked or unsafe operations.Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details"**.
Can some on please tell me how I can correct this?

```
public class BinaryNode{
    Comparable element;
    BinaryNode left;
    BinaryNode right;
    BinaryNode(Comparable theElement,BinaryNode lt,BinaryNode rt){
        element=theElement;
        left=lt;
        right=rt;       
    }
    BinaryNode(Comparable theElement){
        this(theElement,null,null);
    }

}  
public class BinaryTr  {
    private BinaryNode root;
    BinaryTr(){
        root=null;
    }
    public void insert(Comparable x){
        root=insert(root,x);
    }
    public BinaryNode insert(BinaryNode current,Comparable x){
        if (current==null)
            current=new BinaryNode(x);
        else{
            if(current.element.compareTo(x)>0)
                current.left=insert(current.left,x);
        else if (current.element.compareTo(x)<0)
            current.right=insert(current.right,x);
        else{
            System.out.println("Duplicates not allowed");
        }
    }
    return current;
}

public static void main (String args[]){
    BinaryTr t=new BinaryTr();
    t.insert(5);
            t.insert(4);
            t.insert(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's...not an error.  That's just a warning.  Recompile with `-Xlint:unchecked` to see what the warning is telling you.  It may be important.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions the compiler explicitly gave you?  Try that, and if you're still stumped, come back here.  Not before.

Comment: use generic will solve this

Comment: @Makoto I read the other question.I don't know where to use generics.If I specify as <String> would I be able to compare only String.So then wouldn't I be able to insert int.

Comment: *That's the point.*  You're bounding the type to a `String`.  You can't just arbitrarily enter in any old type to it, or you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @Makoto Then if I can only use the tree for a specific type, either int or String without using Compare I could have used just`int element` and not use `CompareTo` method.What's the purpose of using Comparable.Also can you please tell me where I should use the generic.Because I am not familiar with it

Comment: Such a conversation would be too long for this format, but I would encourage you to read up on generics; the Java Trails provides a ton of useful information for beginners.  (By the way:  I would imagine that your type parameter is defined as `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, since you *are* doing `compareTo`.

Comment: @Makoto No I haven't used `<T extends Comparable<T>>`.What's the type parameter,Is it the parameter inside `compareTo()`.Then I am giving  a parameter of type `Comparable`